# failure of Projective Uniformization

Tags: set-theory

How do you show the failure of Projective Uniformization in the generic extension of $L$ which adds $\aleph_{2}$ Cohen reals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\notin L[y]\}$.

Check that this set is $\Pi^1_2$ (this is similar to the proof that there is a $\Delta^1_2$ well-ordering in $L$).

The point is that $A$ does not admit a projective uniformization. It does not really matter that the number of Cohen reals you added is $\aleph_2$; any uncountable number would work. The reason is essentially the same as the reason that choice fails in $L(\mathbb R)$ of the forcing extension (a consequence of the homogeneity of Cohen forcing and the fact that any real parameters used in a projective definition of a set are added by an intermediate countable poset; this allows you to diagonalize and argue by contradiction) so not only there is no projective uniformization of $A$, but not even a uniformization in $L(\mathbb R)$.

By the way, this result was established quite soon after forcing was developed, see

> [MR0205827 (34 #5653)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=205827) Reviewed. Lévy, Azriel. *Definability in axiomatic set theory. I*. In **Logic, methodology and philosophy of science. Proceedings of the 1964 International Congress**, Y. Bar-Hillel, ed., North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1965, pp. 127–151.